# when i press row in my datagrid, how to show picture that in database?

Tags: asp.net

i working on asp.net & C#

i have datagrid that contain my database.

i have table Workers that contain ID,Fname,W_PIC (W_PIC contain the picture)

when i press row in my datagrid how to show the picture in image control

that i has in my web-form ?

(the picture in the database is not a link to picture - its binary array)

Comment: What is the database data type of W_PIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Retrieve Images from a SQL database for display in an Asp.Net Datagrid](http://odetocode.com/articles/172.aspx)